# Get value from application-lcl.properties in an xml configuration Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i have in some spring application , in application-lcl.properties a line with :

```
key1=value1
```

I want to use the value of key1 in another xml like this :

```
<appender name="ELASTIC" class="com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAppender">
    <url>${key1}</url>
```

${key1} doesn't work. Do you know how to do it ? (the .xml already exists )

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use the Spring replacement of properties outside of Spring-managed beans. In this case, Spring will not process the `logback.xml` file for property substitution.

Answer (score -1):

Its a 2 step process

1. Load properties file into java.util.java.util.Properties class object.
2. Use `Properties.storeToXML()` method to write the content as XML

   String inPropertiesFile = "application.properties";
   String outXmlFile = "applicationProperties.xml";

   InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inPropertiesFile); //Input file
   OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outXmlFile);     //Output file

   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.load(is);

   props.storeToXML(os, "application.properties","UTF-8");

Comment: hi , the xml file exists already and i can't append new lines to it via an InputStream

Answer (score -1):

in the xml , put

`<springProperty name="value1" source="key1"/>`

and then use it by calling

`<url>${value1}</url>`